# BeautifulSoup using an iterable instead of string?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I am parsing a Wikipedia metadata file with bs4 and python 3.5

This works for extraction, from a test slice of the (much larger) file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open ("Wikipedia/test.xml", 'r') as xml_file:
    xml = xml_file.read()

print(BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml').select("timestamp"))
```

The issue is that the metadata files are all 12+ gigs, so rather than slurping in the entire file as a string before ensoupification, I'd like to have BeautifulSoup read the data as an iterator (possibly even from gzcat to avoid having the data sitting around in uncompressed files).

However, my attempts to hand BS anything other than a string causes it to choke. Is there a way to get BS to read data as a stream instead of a string?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, BS cannot read from an iterable. You may want to try `lxml`.

Answer (score 2):

You can give BS a file handle object.

```
with open("Wikipedia/test.xml", 'r') as xml_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_file, 'lxml')
```

This is the first example in the documentation of [Making the Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup)

Comment: Thank you, this is great (although of course I realize that reading a 12G file straight to BS still causes a memory error, so I may still have to break up the files...)

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup or lxml has no stream option but you can use `iterparse()` to read large xml files in a chunk

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

for event, elem in etree.iterparse("Wikipedia/test.xml", events=('start', 'end')):
  ....
  if event == 'end':
      ....
      elem.clear() # freed memory
```

read more [here](http://boscoh.com/programming/reading-xml-serially.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xml.etree.cElementTree+iterparse)

Comment: Thanks, and this will be useful when it is from a network stream instead of a file.